# What could be the reason for the following iPhone app crash

Tags: ios, crash-reports, urbanairship.com, crash-log

I am using UrbanAirship in my app and it crashes suddenly when using the app and shows the crash report option on app startup, here is the crash log:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         OlympusiPhone [5075]
Path:            /Users/USER/OlympusiPhone.app/OlympusiPhone
Identifier:      com.olympus.app
Version:         16.0
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-04-07T11:48:30Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xf0000008
Crashed Thread:  28

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6a9e80 _semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   SpringBoardServices                 0x37a0fc4b _SBSProcessAssertionCreateForPID + 423
2   UIKit                               0x343a2d6d -[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:] + 69
3   OlympusiPhone                       0x00130d1d -[UAAnalytics enterBackground] (UAAnalytics.m:305)
4   CoreFoundation                      0x32426349 __CFXNotificationPost + 1421
5   Foundation                          0x32d3db7f -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 71
6   UIKit                               0x3436f133 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 819
7   UIKit                               0x342e52d1 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2469
8   UIKit                               0x342e47ad -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 73
9   UIKit                               0x342e41ef _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6199
10  GraphicsServices                    0x35ffb5f7 _PurpleEventCallback + 591
11  GraphicsServices                    0x35ffb227 PurpleEventCallback + 35
12  CoreFoundation                      0x324aa3e7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
13  CoreFoundation                      0x324aa38b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 139
14  CoreFoundation                      0x324a920f __CFRunLoopRun + 1383
15  CoreFoundation                      0x3241c23d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
16  CoreFoundation                      0x3241c0c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
17  GraphicsServices                    0x35ffa33b _GSEventRunModal + 75
18  UIKit                               0x343382b9 _UIApplicationMain + 1121
19  OlympusiPhone                       0x000bae9f main (main.m:32)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6aa5d0 _kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a5e1378 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 36

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6a9e30 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x324aa2bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131
2   CoreFoundation                      0x324a9031 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3241c23d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3241c0c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   WebCore                             0x3841b395 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 445
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6a9e30 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x324aa2bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131
2   CoreFoundation                      0x324a9031 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3241c23d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3241c0c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   Foundation                          0x32d6988d +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 309
6   Foundation                          0x32ded231 __NSThread__main__ + 973
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6a9e30 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x324aa2bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131
2   CoreFoundation                      0x324a9031 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3241c23d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3247ac4b _CFRunLoopRun + 99
5   OlympusiPhone                       0x0011d303 +[UA_ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (UA_ASIHTTPRequest.m:4795)
6   Foundation                          0x32ded231 __NSThread__main__ + 973
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6ba08c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a60b875 _pthread_cond_timedwait + 45
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x363f0dfb __ZN3WTF15ThreadCondition9timedWaitERNS_5MutexEd + 107
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x36503537 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 83
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x36516033 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6ba08c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a615cfd _pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x364966e1 JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 145
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x36496625 JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 145
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x36516033 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6ba594 ___select + 20
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6a9e30 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x324aa2bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131
2   CoreFoundation                      0x324a9031 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3241c23d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3241c0c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   WebCore                             0x384b5cd1 _ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 145
6   JavaScriptCore                      0x36516033 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6a9e30 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x324aa2bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131
2   CoreFoundation                      0x324a9031 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3241c23d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3241c0c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   AudioToolbox                        0x31efc90b GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 139
6   AudioToolbox                        0x31edd9f5 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 297
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6ba08c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a615cfd _pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x363f0dcd __ZN3WTF15ThreadCondition9timedWaitERNS_5MutexEd + 61
3   WebCore                             0x3862fe81 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WebCore::StorageTask> WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::StorageTask>::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool ()(WebCore::StorageTask*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WebCore::StorageTask*), double) + 57
4   WebCore                             0x3862fe35 WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 125
5   JavaScriptCore                      0x36516033 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6ba08c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a615cfd _pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   CoreMedia                           0x32a027c9 _FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 269
3   MediaToolbox                        0x334f494f fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 55
4   CoreMedia                           0x32a2088b figThreadMain + 195
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6ba08c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a615cfd _pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   CoreMedia                           0x32a027c9 _FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 269
3   MediaToolbox                        0x334f494f fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 55
4   CoreMedia                           0x32a2088b figThreadMain + 195
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6a9e30 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   MediaToolbox                        0x334fab81 FigExpressNotificationThread + 101
2   CoreMedia                           0x32a2088b figThreadMain + 195
3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6130e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 25:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 26:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 27:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 28 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3a1c15d0 _objc_msgSend + 16
1   OlympusiPhone                       0x001345c3 -[UASQLite executeUpdate:] (UASQLite.m:299)
2   OlympusiPhone                       0x001369af __45-[UAAnalyticsDBManager addEvent:withSession:]_block_invoke_0 (UAAnalyticsDBManager.m:108)
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a5e0793 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a5e3b3b _dispatch_queue_drain + 143
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a5e167d _dispatch_queue_invoke + 45
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a5e4613 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 211
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a5e47d9 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 93
8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f1 _pthread_wqthread + 361

Thread 29:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a6bad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a6087f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 28 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x1d8aee90     r1: 0x37f89fb0     r2: 0x3a83a4c0     r3: 0x1cd33cd0 
    r4: 0xf0000000     r5: 0x00000004     r6: 0x1d8aee90     r7: 0x08b0eec8 
    r8: 0x1cd33cd0     r9: 0x0dfe27ec    r10: 0x00000004    r11: 0x1cdc2e50 
    ip: 0x3a813718     sp: 0x08b0ee88     lr: 0x3241fbfd     pc: 0x3a1c15d0 
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

What could be the reason for this crash?
Thanks

Comment: The crash is in thread 28. It's in your code. `UASQLite.m` line 299.

Comment: Which binary are you using 1.0.6 . Upgrade to 1.0.7 hopefully it will help.

Comment: @rmaddy: UA stands for "Urban Airship". So, I guess it's Urban Airship code.

Comment: It appears you have the source code for that. Take a look at the `UASQLite.m` line 299. Otherwise, this should be posted to Urban Airship support. If there is a bug in their code, they would want to know about it.

Comment: Thanks for your time, the issue was with their library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with v1.3.6 of the UrbanAirship library.
Urban Airship also does Analytics, although I wasn't using it, but UrbanAirship was storing events in their database and that code was causing the crash.

To resolve, use the library v1.3.7+.

To use, remove the old references and add the new ones.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe you breifly explain the problem and the solution.